# Document digital signature is both validated and invalid?

Tags: certificate, libreoffice, digital-signature

I am using Libre Office to try to sign a document. Libre has notified me that my certificate is both validated but also invalid.

[image]

**What do?**

I have used this signature multiple times today already on multiple systems, so I know that it is "legit".

**EDIT:** As grawity has noted in his answer I have read this dialog wrong. Though the issue is that right after signing the document the signature becomes invalid, even with no changes. Just after selecting my certificate for signature and the "Sign Document" dialog is closed and I am returned to the "Digital Signatures" dialog and the certificate I selected is shown, it is immediately shown as invalid. Any ideas?

**EDIT 2:** After reviewing the ["About Digital Signatures"](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/About_Digital_Signatures) help page I think my issue is that "The signature and the certificate are OK, but not all parts of the document are signed." as a result of seeing the second icon listed in the "Signature Status" table on the linked page.

Though I don't see much information about how to remedy this issue of having "not all " of the document signed. (I am using Windows 10 and Libre Office 5.2.3.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing two separate things. The screenshot says that the *certificate* itself (the signing tool) is valid, but the *signature* made with it isn't.

Digital signatures aren't merely the certificate itself glued onto the document, so you *aren't* using "the same signature" every time – each signature is different because it also contains a hash of the document contents, so that mismatches can be detected – which is the whole point.

In other words, the document no longer matches the signature, possibly because it was edited or just corrupted.

Comment: Hmm, I am going to post an edit to the original post.

Comment: @grawity is correct;  This can happen if you modify the document after its been signed.  You can fix this by, removing the signature that is there, and adding the signature back to the document after a local copy of the document has been saved.